# Calculating the size of a node in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this node in Realtime Database:

```
{
 fieldA: 123,
 field2: '456',
 field3: true,
}
```

How is this calculated on an individual node basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about the storage and bandwidth cost of transferring this object, Firebase uses pretty much the JSON size for the node without whitespace. So for your code:

```js
let node = {
 fieldA: 123,
 field2: '456',
 field3: true,
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(node).length);
```